# Could not find C:\Development\android-sdk-windows\tools\emulator.exe?

Tags: java, eclipse, android-sdk-2.3

Everything was working fine , until I decided to update my Android SDK manager . But i accidentally switch off my PC while the updating process . and now it displays the message 
"Could not find C:\Development\android-sdk-windows\tools\emulator.exe!"

and every project has an error now . Will i have to download the Android SDK again or is there a simpler way to fix it ?

Is there a way to restore eclipse?

Comment: Personally, I'd probably re-download it. It would probably take less time than troubleshooting it manually. Unless you have a 14.4k modem.

Answer (score 1):

**make sure** your **sdk manager** work's fine and if it's,you should **add** it to **eclipse** again.
if it doesn't work yet,**reinstall** your sdk manager and give the **new sdk path to eclipse**

Comment: just reinstall sdk manager in your computer,and give the new sdk path to eclipse